# How to get at the dotnet run command Visual Studio uses

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core app and all runs fine when I press the play button in Visual Studio, but when I try to run it from the console with `dotnet run` it fails with errors.  How can I get the exact `dotnet run` command that visual studio uses to run the project?

The Error:

> C:\MySolution\ConstantsProject\Sensor.cs (94, 31): error CS0103: The name 'EnumCommon' does not exist in the current context [c:\MySolution\ConstantsProject\Constants.csproj'.

EnumCommon is an enum that exists in a dll referenced by Constants.csproj.  As a matter of fact, dotnet build won't even build the solution, but VS2022 does build it.  `dotnet build` fails with the same error

Comment: Please show the errors you get. VS has a bit customized pipeline at least for building the project (for example sometimes for newer versions it will not be able to even build the application which can be build with `dotnet build`), potentially for `run` it does something too.

Comment: Ideally a [mre] would be great.

Comment: I just need the command line entry that VS executes to run my project.  The error: error CS0103: The name 'xxx' does not exist in the current context.  This error happens when I simply use `dotnet run` in my project directory.  It runs fine however from VS2022

Comment: TBH I have mainly switched from VS to Rider and not actually sure that VS is actually using `dotnet run` internally.

Comment: Try `dotnet run -c Debug`. If it works - you have some problem in the code due to conditional compilation. The same will happen with VS if you'll try ruining in release mode.

Comment: Can you please add part of code resulting in the error? `dotnet run` should output file and line number.

Comment: @GuruStron Visual Studio does not call `dotnet run` on an `F5` debug. It calls the exe directly and attaches the debugger.

Comment: @Kit yep, that was my guess. But have not dug too deeply into the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you cannot get a `dotnet run` based command that Visual Studio uses to execute the project on the "play button" (aka a debugging session, hotkey `F5`) because VS does not run `dotnet run`.

Instead, VS will run the executable directly and attach the debugger. The debugger does not necessarily have all the same references at runtime that VS has during build time due to dynamic loading/runtime timings, hence the error).

When you used the fully-specified type name of the enums, you're forcing the debugger to have the dependent assembly loaded, if it is not already loaded.

All that's a bit of a hand-wave, but the key thing is that runtime debug environment != build-time environment. You might be able to ensure the enums are available by accessing them prior to where they're used in the datasets, but that is a bit artificial.

While `dotnet run` isn't used, if you need to get the process running when you do an `F5` debug, you can either use the `Process` class or you can simply inspect `launchsettings.json` for the launch profile currently configured to run for `F5`.